# What is the energy source for Earth movements?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, orbital-motion, earth

What is the source of energy responsible for Earth movements (rotation, translation, etc.)?

Comment: Why would a source of energy be required for non-accelerating movements?

Comment: @JMac Neither the revolution of the Earth around the Sun, nor the rotation of the Earth on its axis, are non-accelerating movements. (Nevertheless, neither needs an energy source to keep them going.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Energy is not required for movement.  You only need energy for changes in movement, such as some accelerations.

For the way we usually think about the Earth's movements, there is no energy source because it's already in motion.  Orbital motion, in particular, is a kind which requires no additional energy... kind of like how it takes no additional energy to keep moving when you're slipping on ice.

If you want to get deeper than that, the energy which got the Earth moving in its current way did indeed come from somewhere.  It came from the gravitational potential energy of dust as that dust coalesced into clumps, and later into planets.  But we rarely choose to think that far in the past.  Usually we say that the Earth has its kinetic energy, and the path of its orbit does not change that energy.

Comment: Minor note (to v1): the path of Earth's orbit *does* change its kinetic energy, but only to the extent that Earth's orbit is non-circular, and in a periodic way.

Comment: @rob Good point.  There is some transfer of kinetic energy to potential energy as the Earth moves a little further from the sun in its orbit, and a transfer back as the Earth moves closer.  Curse you, reality, and your little-yet-important nuances!

Comment: Please, correct me if I understood it wrong: Earth "has" a constant amount of mechanical energy (Potencial + Kinetic). It moves in a certain trajectory on the deformed space created by the sun. In this movement, potential and kinetic energies change but are balanced, keeping mechanical energy constant forever and ever. Am I right?

Comment: @RobertoDiasAlgarte Correct, within reason (drag against the handful of hydrogen atoms in space, etc.)  Its the same kind of balance we see with a pendulum, where the energy is all potential at the highest point, that energy transfers to kinetic as it races the the bottom, and then back as it reaches the other high point.  The only difference is that it's really easy to intuitively see that in a pendulum, and takes a bit more digging to see it in orbital mechanics.

Comment: I knew it !!! I refused to believe that there was no friction at all and the movement was free from any dissipation!

Comment: @RobertoDiasAlgarte Hurrah!  Yes, there is *some* dissipation.  The [Interplanetary Medium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interplanetary_medium) has something like 5 particles per cubic centimeter, and we do see drag.  I have not been able to find any estimates for how large this drag is, but obviously its the kind of thing that only adds up meaningfully over millions (or billions) of years.  Worth noting is that, on the 100 million year time scale, we also have to start considering the chaotic movements of the planets.

Comment: The planets do interact on each other, and that system exhibits chaotic behaviors.  They are relatively predictable on the scale of <10million years, but as you look out to 100 million years, these effects make it very hard to predict.  Moral of the story: reality is *always* more complicated than the model (which is why we love our [spherical cows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cow) so much!)

Comment: Indeed! Models are just human abstractions and we love what we create. But now something frightening ocurred to me: rigoriously speaking, if there is dissipation on the Earth movement, are we slowly getting closer to the sun?

Comment: @RobertoDiasAlgarte Yes, at some timescale.  We are not in an eternal orbit.  However, I could not find any data on how fast that is ocuring.  It is expected that, at the end of the sun's life, it's radius will expand enough to envelop the Earth's orbit, and that will most certainly be the end of our concerns regarding interplanetary medium drag.  I could not find anything regarding how much our orbit will have decayed by the time the sun does so (roughly 4 billion year from now, give or take few).

Comment: If you are really interested in those long time scales, I recommend a fiction book by Stephen Baxter called *Manifold: Time*.  It is the only book I have come across which does a reasonable job of trying to capture these extremely long time scales in a way that the intuition has a glimmer of a chance of comprehending.

Comment: I'll buy the book, Cort! Thanks for all the valuable information. Best Regards.